# How to autostart docker desktop in the background?

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2, autostart

I am using wsl2 with Windows 11 but to use docker within the wsl i have to start the docker desktop application for windows.

I am able to add docker desktop to autostart so that it opens up on startup. But since i only use docker within the wsl i don't need the window to pop up everytime.

It's not a big deal, but it would be nice to be able to start docker desktop in the background somehow or just stop the window from popping up on startup.

Would be nice if anyone had a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 'Docker Dashboard' to pop up you can unselect checkbox below `Open Docker Dashboard at startup'

[image: Example]